# How to create file in %windir% correctly?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, batch-file, visual-studio-2012

This creates a bat file, and runs it. It works without any problems.

```
Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder

sb.AppendLine("@echo off")
sb.AppendLine("set hostspath=%windir%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts")
sb.AppendLine("echo 99.127.158.117 www.example.com >> %hostspath%")
sb.AppendLine("exit")

IO.File.WriteAllText("fileName.bat", sb.ToString())
Process.Start("fileName.bat")
```

However when I  try to change the file dir, like

```
IO.File.WriteAllText("%windir%\fileName.bat", sb.ToString())
Process.Start("%windir%\fileName.bat")
```

It doesnt create and run it. What is the correct way to do that ? (exe is running as an administrator)

Comment: you cannot write to WinDir.  it was never a good idea and now the OS prevents it.  In cases where it seems to work, it actually writes it to Users.....

Comment: Do you get any error? What is the error?

Comment: the *way* you are doing it wont work either unless there is a folder literally named "%windir%"

Comment: @Plutonix , what is the correct way to do that? &Vikas no errors